# SAM invoke won't take local env vars

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have a sample SAM application with basic endpoints. I just want to run it locally by:

```
sam local invoke -e events/event-post-item.json putItemFunction --profile myprofile -n local.json
```

`local.json` is as follows:

```
{
    "getAllItems": {
        "SAMPLE_TABLE": "mywebservices-SampleTable-1BS18COYN2SHV"
    },
    "getById": {
        "SAMPLE_TABLE": "mywebservices-SampleTable-1BS18COYN2SHV"
    },
    "putItem": {
        "SAMPLE_TABLE": "mywebservices-SampleTable-1BS18COYN2SHV"
    }
}
```

And following is the code for `putItemFunction`

```
// Create clients and set shared const values outside of the handler

// Create a DocumentClient that represents the query to add an item
const dynamodb = require('aws-sdk/clients/dynamodb');

const docClient = new dynamodb.DocumentClient();

// Get the DynamoDB table name from environment variables
const tableName = process.env.SAMPLE_TABLE;


/**
 * A simple example includes a HTTP post method to add one item to a DynamoDB table.
 */
exports.putItemHandler = async (event) => {
    
    const { body, httpMethod, path } = event;
    if (httpMethod !== 'POST') {
        throw new Error(`postMethod only accepts POST method, you tried: ${httpMethod} method.`);
    }
    // All log statements are written to CloudWatch by default. For more information, see
    // https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-logging.html
    console.log('received:', JSON.stringify(event));

    // Get id and name from the body of the request
    const { id, name } = JSON.parse(body);

    // Creates a new item, or replaces an old item with a new item
    // https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#put-property
    const params = {
        TableName: tableName,
        Item: { id, name },
    };
    await docClient.put(params).promise();

    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body,
    };

    console.log(`response from: ${path} statusCode: ${response.statusCode} body: ${response.body}`);
    return response;
};
```

I run this, and I get a "resource not found" error. I have made sure that the profile details are correct.

The proble is with this line in the handler: `const tableName = process.env.SAMPLE_TABLE;`

If I hard code the table name here, it works fine. Otherwise the function produces `tableName` value "SampleTable" always...

It should take the value form the env variables I have provided. Not "SampleTable"... What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The keys in the [local environment file](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-using-invoke.html#serverless-sam-cli-using-invoke-environment-file) `local.json` are the lambda function names.

`"putItemFunction:"`, not `"putItem:"` in your case.